# Convert input field string to Int in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So im very new to making APP ad Swift, im trying to do some very simple input in text fields, take the value, and use them as Int's for some calculations.

But something is not working correct with the 'var distance'

```
        var handicapTal:Int
        var MagicNumber:Int
        var handicap = inputHCP.text.toInt()
        var distance = inputDistance.text.toInt()

        if (handicap >= 0 && handicap <= 20)
        {
            handicapTal = 30
        }
        else if(handicap > 20 && handicap <= 40){
            handicapTal = 10
        }

        MagicNumber = distance - handicapTal
```

Its the last line of code that  give an error. It says Fatal error: Cant unwrap Optional.None

Answer (score 9, accepted):

distance, in your example, is an Int? otherwise known as an optional Int.  .toInt() returns Int? since it is possible for the conversion from String to Int to fail.  See the following example:

```
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> let a = "12"
a: String = "12"
  2> let b = a.toInt()
b: Int? = 12
  3> let c = "Hello"
c: String = "Hello"
  4> let d = c.toInt()
d: Int? = nil
  5> if let e = a.toInt() { println("e = \(e)") }
e = 12
  6> if let f = c.toInt() { println("Huh?") }
  7>
```

Comment: But how can i use the Int? type to do more calculations with?
Can I in your example do 'let g = b + b?

Comment: @RasmusBidstrup Yes, you can.

Comment: @Rasmum, if nil == b { // handle error } else { let g = b! + b! }

Answer (score 1):

I found your problem! You first should initialize handicapTal.
You can do that with : `var handicaptal: Int!`. When you put a `!` behind it it will be set to nil. Or just set it to 0. `var handicaptal: Int = 0` I tried this code and it runs without errors!

Comment: I believe that instead of using an implicitly unwrapped optional type of Int!, which can be nil, it would be better to test for nil and use the unwrap operator such as if nil == handicapTal then { // handle error } else { // use handicapTal! in expressions }

Comment: the reason for the down-vote is that if you use an implicitly unwrapped options such as Int! and there is an error in toInt() the variable will get the value of nil.  If you don't check for nil, then the program will crash when toInt() returns nil.  Did you test your code with something like "ABC".toInt() which will return nil and could crash the whole program if you use the result without checking if it is nil.

Comment: This answer is months old. Swift was 2 weeks in Beta. So this answer possibly could be un useful right now. But at the time it maybe was the right way. Apple did change some stuff about Swift, so I don't see the point on commenting on this.

Comment: A lot of answer on Swift related questions give errors right now with the new Swift code. So this answer shouldn't be downvoted. But it's your right to vote so what ever.