# String does not have a member named 'text' error in Swift

Tags: xcode, string, swift, compiler-errors

I'm having issue with getting my **let c:Int? = conversion.text.toInt()** to convert correctly.  I'm keep getting '[String]' does not have a member named 'text' error.  Anybody know how to convert variable into integer?

I can't seem to get **a** to multiply to **c**.

```
    @IBOutlet var pickerView1: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var enterUnits: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var answerConversion: UITextField!
    var brand = ["m to feet","cm to inches", "mm to inches"]
    var conversion = ["3","4", "5”]
```

pickerView function

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {
if pickerView.tag == 0 {

            let a:Int? = enterUnits.text.toInt()
            let b:Int? = answerConversion.text.toInt()
            let c:Int? = conversion.text.toInt()
            let answer = (a!) * (c!)
            textField1.text = brand[row]
            answerConversion.text = conversion[row]
            answerConversion.text = "\(answer)”

}
```

Comment: Your variable conversion is not a string, but an array of strings, so you have to convert its elements to ints, not the array.

Comment: how would i write that line of code?  I been trying to convert it into ints..but no such luck.

Comment: In this very specific case: let intArray = conversion.map { $0.toInt()! } , but keep in mind, that if will cause runtime error, if any element of the array is not convertible to int.

Comment: Is there a better way of rewriting the code?  any suggestion...thanks.

Comment: not sure if thats just here, but you're having wrong "" in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229947/convert-input-field-string-to-int-in-swift) that you don't necessarily need the .text. Try to just use

```
let c:Int? = conversion.toInt()
```

Oh and since `conversion` is an array, you would have to access the string you want to use. Try doing that with something like `conversion[index]` (insert the index which you' like to use)

Another way I found is to do it the following:

```
let c:Int = Int(conversion[index].bridgeToObjectiveC().intValue)
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Try it but didn't work...still getting '[String]' does not have a member named 'toInt' error....

Comment: may I ask for what exactly you have / need the array?

Comment: basically, i'm trying to set up a basically calculation with a pickerview. when i select m to feet, it does a simple calculation.  If you have any other suggestion that doesn't require an array, let me know.